# Copy to clipboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

I want to be able to copy text to the clipboard using Javascript.

I found the [JQuery Copy plugin](http://yangshuai.googlepages.com/jquerycopyplugin) on the web but this does not work
in Firefox (after testing it only IE).

I found another one called ZeroClipboard but this seems
to rely on Flash player 9 and 10.

Is there any other solution that will work in all browsers?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: dup: 400212, 1701543, 233719, ...

Answer (score 5):

The guys working on Bespin had to deal with this.

[Episode 1](http://almaer.com/blog/supporting-the-system-clipboard-in-your-web-applications-what-a-pain)

[Episode 2](http://almaer.com/blog/supporting-the-system-clipboard-in-your-web-applications-part-two)